# How to use TF datasets with images for multi-GPU training in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multi-gpu

I am creating my TensorFlow `Dataset` like this:

```py
@tf.function
def load_images(image_path, label):
    image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    image = vgg16.preprocess_input(image)  # VGG16 is my base model
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    return (image, label)

training_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_paths, train_labels_le))
training_dataset = (
    training_dataset.shuffle(1024)
    .map(load_images, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    .prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
)
```

Then I build and fit my Keras model with a mirrored strategy for multi-GPU training:

```py
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
    keras_model = build_model()  # based on tf.keras.applications.VGG16
    keras_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
keras_model.fit(training_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS)
```

However, calling `.fit()` leads to the following warning:

> AUTO sharding policy will apply DATA sharding policy as it failed to apply FILE sharding policy because of the following reason: Found an unsharable source dataset: name: "TensorSliceDataset/_2"

So I try to set these options, as suggested by the warning:

```py
options = tf.data.Options()
options.experimental_distribute.auto_shard_policy = tf.data.experimental.AutoShardPolicy.DATA
training_dataset.with_options(options)
```

But this does not solve it, the warning is still being printed.
So how is one supposed to correctly use a TF dataset for Keras multi-GPU training?

EDIT: Link to [minimal working example source code](https://gist.github.com/haimat/d5f179b23e61c2b80ba424f988b90c9e).

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://keras.io/guides/distributed_training/)?

Comment: @M.Innat Yes, I am following this documentation. There it says to use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`, which is what I am doing in my code as you can see above, but still this error/warning. I have added a link to my minimal working example.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @Stiefel Yes ... but probably not what you want to read. We took the opportunity and switch from Keras to PyTorch. A step we wanted to do since quite a while now, and these multi-GPU training problems were a good reason to finally switch to PyTorch. For the records: Training with multiple GPUs there is super-easy, just 2-3 more lines of code and we haven't had any regret since that switch.